# Test SQL Server Express connectivity using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linux, windows

Apologies - this is a bit of a newbie (I'm not a DBA) 
**Question:**  I'd like to test remote access to `MS SQL Server Express` from a `linux box` using `MySQL`.  Is there any additional configuration required on the SQL Express side?

If I'm testing access to another MySQL database I can just to the following:

```
mysql --host ip_address --port=3308 --user=username -p
```

Then after entering my password I can get my remote "mysql>" prompt.

I guess my question is this - is there an equivalent way to test connectivity to MS SQL Server Express remotely?  Can I connect to an MS Sql Server in this way or do I need to provide instance name or specific Db perhaps?

Thanks in advance!

I should also mention that current attempts to do this result in an error even if trying `ports 1433/1434/1521` instead of `3308`:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip_address' (111)

It seems to be assuming connection to another MySQL server by default.

I believe error 111 means "connection refused" so I'm thinking this might be a MS SQL Server configuration problem?  I'm assuming this is a SQL-generated error.

Comment: take look at this:[how-do-i-access-mysql-server-from-the-shell-prompt-command-line](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-access-mysql-server-from-the-shell-prompt-command-line/)

Comment: Thanks Melon!  I think I'm OK accessing MySQL server from command line but I'm wondering if I can use the same method to connect to MS SQL Server (Microsoft's incarnation).  I'm thinking MS might be a bit more locked down by default or perhaps uses a different port number, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual SQL may be more-or-less standard across DBMS's, but the way you actually talk to them individually is quite different: there isn't even a standard for them to deviate from!

Your mySQL client is trying to talk to a MySQL database server, and sending information the a MySQL server would expect. This is being received by a SQL Server database server which expects something quite different, and is saying effectively "Talk sense! No? Go away."

What actually talks to the database usually is the driver you select. This is how e.g. C# code on Windows can talk to many different database servers: you provide the right driver and specify it in the connection string. I have no idea whether a SQL Server driver exists for Linux, nor how you can specify the driver to your mySQL client. You'll have to get both working somehow.

The good news is that Linux drivers do exist for SQL Server e.g. [here](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/getting-started.html). That still leaves how you tell the mySQL client to use it (which I'm not sure would be possible).

Comment: Thanks Simon.  I suspected worst case may be compatibility issues alright.  Thank you for the link to the driver also.  I'll give it a try...